# R marmap getNOAA.bathy Error in if (ncol(x) == 3 & !exists("bathy", inherits = FALSE)) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, package

I've been trying to get bathymetry lines from marmap and recently got the following error message when getNOAA.bathy function is called

```
Querying NOAA database ...This may take seconds to minutes, depending on grid size
Error in if (ncol(x) == 3 & !exists("bathy", inherits = FALSE)) { : argument is of length zero
```

This happens even with something as simple as

```
map <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1=10,lon2=19,lat1=67,lat2=71,resolution=10, keep=TRUE)
```

I updated the package to the latest version (1.0.4) as I read that there could be issues related to server access. I've also tried running the above script in R rather than RStudio, but the error persists...
The function works fine if I use previously downloaded data, but now I needed use use another set of coordinates for a new map.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to (re)install both `rgdal` and `raster` packages. This is already documented [here on the GitHub Issue pages](https://github.com/ericpante/marmap/issues/10) of the `marmap` package.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else looking, the reported error can also result from the server being down - R doesn't give any indication of this.  You can check https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/alerts for scheduled outages.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For several months now, the same error message seem to have plagued Windows users, event with all packages up to date.

`marmap v1.0.9` is now available on GitHub:

```
remotes::install_github("ericpante/marmap")
```

This version should solve this infamous Error message:

```
Error in if (ncol(x) == 3 & !exists("bathy", inherits = FALSE)) { :
argument is of length zero
```

I have been able to confirm that the error was due to a limitation in the length of urls that the `raster` package can handle on Windows. The geotif files from NOAA's servers are now downloaded with `utils::download.file()` in a temporary file on the user's disk and then imported in R using `raster::raster()`.

`marmap v1.0.9` will be available on CRAN servers in the next few days.